# Why should I dereference a pointer before calling the operator() in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I am trying to create a generic `Distribution` class that wraps many of the available distributions in `<random>` header.

In order to do that, I create a pointer to the intended distribution inside the derived class (check code below). All the distributions in `<random>` implement `operator()` to get a random number according to the considered distribution. If `distribution` was not a pointer, then it would suffice for me to call `distribution(this->randomNumGen)` in order to get a random number.

However, I declare `distribution` as a pointer and thus the line marked as `//THIS LINE` below would fail to compile if I would draw a random number by `distribution(this->randomNumGen)` with the following error:

> expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

and I have to call the `operator()` as `(*this->distribution)(this->randomNumGen)`.

- Why do I have to dereference a pointer before calling `operator()`?

I have the following header:

```
class Distribution_c
{
public:
    Distribution_c(std::mt19937&);
    ~Distribution_c();

    virtual std::vector<double> GetSample(int);

protected:
    std::mt19937 randomNumGen;
};

class UniformDistribution : public Distribution_c
{
public:
    UniformDistribution(double, double, std::mt19937&);
    ~UniformDistribution();
    virtual std::vector<double> GetSample(int);
private:
    double x0;
    double x1;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double>* distribution; // POINTER TO THE DISTRIBUTION
};
```

and the following implementation

```
UniformDistribution::UniformDistribution(double x0, double x1, std::mt19937& rng)
    : Distribution_c(rng)
{
    this->x0 = x0;
    this->x1 = x1;
    this->distribution = new std::uniform_real_distribution<double>(x0, x1);
}
UniformDistribution::~UniformDistribution()
{
    delete this->distribution;
}
std::vector<double> UniformDistribution::GetSample(int N)
{
    std::vector<double> v(N);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < N)
    {
        v.push_back((*this->distribution)(this->randomNumGen)); // THIS LINE
        i++;
    }
}

Distribution_c::Distribution_c(std::mt19937& rng)
{
    this->randomNumGen = rng;
}
std::vector<double> Distribution_c::GetSample(int N)
{
    return std::vector<double>();
}
Distribution_c::~Distribution_c()
{
}
```

Comment: I don't see any pointer-to-function here.

Comment: I am new to c++, could you clarify? tks :)

Comment: There is no pointer-to-function here. `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>` is a functor, not a function.

Comment: thanks for the correction, although that was the best way I found to express myself giving this is my second coding experience in c++

Comment: Also: UniformDistribution violates the rule of three/five.

Comment: `(*distribution)(randomNumGen)` would suffice; you don't need to use `this->` everywhere. You need to dereference the pointer get to what it points to; but it's not at all clear why you chose to use a pointer instead of just having a member variable of type `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>`.

Comment: And if a pointer is needed, it should be `std::unique_ptr`, to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @AlanStokes: I am simply more familiar with the `new` notation. I only superficially know the differences between the two approaches you mentioned, like the first is stored in heap memory whereas the second in stack. I don't really understand what would be the advantage of the second though (I have googled it a lot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I have to convert the object to a function pointer before calling operator()

You don't have to and you can't either. It wouldn't work. A pointer-to-object cannot be converted to a pointer-to-function. Even if that was permitted, it would be pretty much meaningless: by converting the object to a function pointer and calling it, you would make the control flow jump to whatever memory address the object happens to be at. And since it's not a function and presumably doesn't contain sensible executable code, it would be undefined behavior (and most likely a crash).

The code

```
(*this->distribution)
```

is **not a conversion to function pointer!** It simply means that you **dereference** the pointer-to-object, obtaining the object itself, to which you can now apply the `()` operator.

Alternatively, you can make your intent a bit clearer and emphasize that you've got a function object with an overloaded call operator, by invoking the operator directly using

```
distribution->operator()(randomNumGen);
```

This notation treats the operator as a normal non-static member function (called `operator()`), and parametrizes it accordingly.

Comment: It may be useful to note that one can also say `distribution->operator()(randomNumGen)`

Comment: Maybe I should rewrite my question to express correctly my idea?